# don't have any CustomActionAttribute in VS2010

Tags: wix, custom-action, votive

I am trying to write a custom actions class library for my WiX install package. I've read that I should use CustomActionAttribute to mark the methods that I am planning to call from install package. There is no Votive plugin for VS2010, so when I type [CustomAction] above my method name, VS2010 doesn't find it. So what should I do to write a custom action method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is Voitve support for Visual Studio 2010 in Wix 3.5 and up.  With Votive you get a project template for creating managed custom actions which will set up all of the dependencies you need to add the CustomAction attribute.

You can add a reference to the Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll to resolve the reference manually, but the project template sets up a few more needed steps to create the CA.

Comment: I've downloaded and installed latest wix build, but I just don't see any wix projects in VS2010. I don't know why that votive tool doesn't work in my VS2010.

Comment: Ah, never mind, I just haven't noticed the "windows installer xml" project group :) . Let this question be closed for now.

Answer (score 1):

From [this](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/4/28/Change-of-plans-for-WiX-v3.5) and other blog posts Rob has made, I thought WiX v3.5's Votive had VS2010 support, just not out of the box (last minute ship-decision?). Someone correct me if I'm wrong.